# Exception thrown: 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' in System.Web.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2015

I was working on a web application on a Three tier architecture and also use a web service in the Business layer and run it on top of `.Net framework 4.0`. The application was running fine on `Visual studio 2012`.

I updated to Visual studio 2015 and all of a sudden I get this error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' in
>   System.Web.dll

I am not able to find as to where the code is being broken.

Answer (score 0):

I had also similar kind of problem, mine got solved after updating **"Microsoft ASP.Net MVC"** package from NuGet package manager

If update option is not available then you can reinstall package after removing it

Comment: I am using web forms and not MVC. Nevertheless when I tried to update the package it says: 

_You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the
 package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author._